# Authlogic LDAP : encrypt communication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap, authlogic

I have a rails app with authlogic and LDAP, but my problem is i can see all the users password on the log file, is there something to fix to encrypt those passwords.
For ldap i use :encryption simple_TLS

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 12):

This is the way I do it with [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) and [net-ldap](http://github.com/roryo/ruby-net-ldap/):

config/ldap.yml

```
    production:
      host: localhost
      port: 636
      base: ou=people,dc=mydomain
      admin_user: cn=admin,dc=mydomain
      admin_password: password
      ssl: true
```

app/models/ldap_connect.rb

```
    class LdapConnect

      attr_reader :ldap

      def initialize(params = {})
        ldap_config = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/ldap.yml")[RAILS_ENV]
        ldap_options = params
        ldap_options[:encryption] = :simple_tls if ldap_config["ssl"]

        @ldap = Net::LDAP.new(ldap_options)
        @ldap.host = ldap_config["host"]
        @ldap.port = ldap_config["port"]
        @ldap.base = ldap_config["base"]
        @ldap.auth ldap_config["admin_user"], ldap_config["admin_password"] if params[:admin] 
      end

    end
```

app/models/user_session.rb

```
    class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base

      verify_password_method :valid_ldap_credentials?

    end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.validate_password_field = false
    c.logged_in_timeout = 30.minutes
  end

  def dn
    "cn=#{self.email},ou=people,dc=mydomain"
  end

  def valid_ldap_credentials?(password_plaintext)
    ldap = LdapConnect.new.ldap
    ldap.auth self.dn, password_plaintext
    ldap.bind # will return false if authentication is NOT successful
  end

end
```

Comment: Cool, glad it helped, LDAP with authlogic was definitely a challenge to get going! Please upvote and accept the answer if you can. Thanks